# No tidy method for objects of class coxme

Tags: r

I'm very new to using R, or any type of coding for that matter, so this problem may be obvious, but i cant seem to get this part of my code to run as i keep getting the error in the title.

`> tidy_fit1 <- tidy(fit1_full)
Error: No tidy method for objects of class coxme`

I've tried restarting the session from scratch and reinstalling and updating all the packages, as well as trying to use tidy.come and tidy.coxph but none have seemed to work.

Comment: It's kind of referenced in [this thread](https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/issues/123) but the `broom` package (which is where I assume you are getting the `tidy` function from) does not know how to work with `coxme` objects. Since that's a much newer R function and package, it simply does not work with every possible model type from every package out there. If you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output, it may be possible to recommend something else.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As I recall when I was new to R -- please be sure that you have imported library `broom` with `require(broom)` before calling its function `tidy`. And note you can install package `broom` with, for example `install.packages("broom")`.